# Is XACML the unique alternative for access granularity

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I currently use WSO2is 5.9, but I want to be more thorough, when creating rules of access to resources of my web application, limit the action to a certain button within my application for example.

I have read the documentation of WSO2is and other resources, everything guides me that I must use XACML to apply such restrictions within my application.

Is there another alternative to XACML? I see a very high complexity in using this proposal.

For now in OIC claims I get the role but I don't see how to limit to functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adaptive authentication scripts also for having some access control in the service provider level instead of using XACML. Please refer to this documentation on Adaptive Authentication script.https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adaptive-authentication/https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adaptive-authentication/

For example, if you want to have some role-based access control, you can use the adaptive script by referring here: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-role-based-adaptive-authentication/.

There are some pre-default scenarion, and you can refer them as well. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adaptive-authentication-scenarios/